# PHP CRUD operations with search, and operator

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I am using below function ( i got this from internet) to fetch data from DB and its working fine. If i use where and search condition is not working properly or i have missed some thing. Can any one help me to fix this issue.

```
public function getRows($table,$conditions = array()){
    $sql = 'SELECT ';
    $sql .= array_key_exists("select",$conditions)?$conditions['select']:'*';
    $sql .= ' FROM '.$table;
    if(array_key_exists("where",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' WHERE ';
        $i = 0;
        foreach($conditions['where'] as $key => $value){
            $pre = ($i > 0)?' AND ':'';
            echo $sql .= $pre.$key." = '".$value."'";
            $i++;
        }
    }
    if(array_key_exists("search",$conditions)){
        $sql .= (strpos($sql, 'WHERE') !== false)?'':' WHERE ';
        $i = 0;
        foreach($conditions['search'] as $key => $value){
            $pre = ($i > 0)?' OR ':'';
            $sql .= $pre.$key." = '".$value."'";
            $i++;
        }
    }
    if(array_key_exists("order_by",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' ORDER BY '.$conditions['order_by']; 
    }

    if(array_key_exists("start",$conditions) && array_key_exists("limit",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' LIMIT '.$conditions['start'].','.$conditions['limit']; 
    }elseif(!array_key_exists("start",$conditions) && array_key_exists("limit",$conditions)){
        echo $sql .= ' LIMIT '.$conditions['limit']; 
    }

    $query = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();

    if(array_key_exists("return_type",$conditions) && $conditions['return_type'] != 'all'){
        switch($conditions['return_type']){
            case 'count':
                $data = $query->rowCount();
                break;
            case 'single':
                $data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                break;
            default:
                $data = '';
        }
    }else{
        if($query->rowCount() > 0){
            $data = $query->fetchAll();
        }
    }
    return !empty($data)?$data:false;
}
```

**Function used with where and Search condition**

```
if(!empty($_POST['customer_number'])) {    
    $ajaxData = $auth_user->getRows(
        'tablename', 
        array('where' => array('fieldName'=>$doc)),
        array('search'=> array('fieldname1'=>$_POST['customer_number'], 'fieldname2'=>$_POST['customer_number']))
    );
}
```

**Result of the above code is**

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE cust_consum_type = '1'
```

Expected Result is.

```
select * from tablename where fieldName='somevalue' and fieldname1='somevalue' OR fieldname2='somevalue'
```

Help me to fix this issue.

Comment: First off, `getRows()` only take two arguments while you are passing three so the second array you're passing as the third argument won't be used in any way. Also, you should scrap this code and look into something using parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries, or you will be wide open for [SQL injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Comment: "_Result of the above code is_" Sure it is? `cust_consum_type` doesn't appear anywhere in that code

Comment: One thing to be careful of when doing something like this is that your expected result can have interesting behaviours as you have a mix of `and` with `or` and no brackets to show you the grouping of these parts.

Answer (score 1):

This function is so wrong on so many levels, being critically insecure in the first place.

Instead, use vanilla PDO. Make your function this way

```
public function getRows($sql,$input = array()){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($input);
    return $stmt;
}
```

Then just write your query right away with placeholders, pass the data in pparameters and have the result:

```
$sql = "select * from tablename where fieldName=:fieldName 
       and (fieldname1=:fieldName1 OR fieldname2=:fieldName2)";
$input = ['fieldName'=>$doc,
         'fieldname1'=>$_POST['customer_number'],
         'fieldname2'=>$_POST['customer_number']];
$data = $db->getRows($sql, $input)->fetchAll();
```

it will be safe, clean, always working, safe, flexible, safe from SQL injections and syntax errors.